# Can I create a boost::shared_ptr to a local variable?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have some methods that take a reference to a given object, and some are taking `boost::shared_ptr`. So far in my test method I created a `shared_ptr` pointing to one of these objects and pass `*ptr` to the methods expecting a reference. Is it possible to do it the other way round, e.g. create a local object on the stack, and then create a shared pointer to it in a safe way, to arrive at the straightforward alternative to `&obj` operator with traditional pointers?

Comment: Keep in mind that those methods probably expect to keep the pointer alive even after they return. If not, they should have taken a `T&` instead.

Comment: As long as nothing ever duplicates or stores that pointer, and nothing is referencing that object after your function exits.  If someone is expecting a pointer instead of a reference, it's probably for a reason - make sure none of the functions you pass this pointer to expect the object to still exist after your function exits.

Comment: @MSalters, this is a test method, so everything is going to be cleaned up once this method is finished. You have a valid point though!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

void null_deleter(int *)
{}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    boost::shared_ptr<int> p(&i, &null_deleter);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

If you find you need this, something is probably horribly wrong with your code.

If the functions take a shared pointer, it should be because they *need* to extend the lifetime of the object. If they don't need to extend the lifetime of the object, they should take a reference.

With what you're doing, they *can't* extend the lifetime of the object. If they need to, and can't, they may wind up accessing an object that has gone out of scope through a copy of the shared pointer you passed them. Boom.

It's slightly possible this might make sense. It may be that they need to extend the lifespan but you will make sure that the object remains valid longer than the longest they might possibly need to extend it. But I'd still strongly suggest not doing this. It's incredibly fragile and makes all the code you call dependent on exactly how the calling code behaves.

Comment: There might be cases you'll need to do s.th. like this, if you have other interfaces (may be beyond your control) that expect `shared_ptr`s explicitly instead of a templated parameter with pointer behavior. +1 though, in general I agree.

Comment: @g-makulik: The thing is, if those interfaces expect a `shared_ptr`, they almost certainly also expect they can extend the object's lifetime. Otherwise, those interfaces are probably broken. (Of course, doing what the OP wants may be better than fixing them given the realities we have to work with it.)

Answer (score 6):

You can pass an appropriate deleter in the constructor of the form:

```
template<class Y, class D> shared_ptr(Y * p, D d);
```

The deleter object must do nothing in its `operator()()`, such as the function:

```
template <typename T>
void no_op(T*) {}
```

with which you can then construct:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Foo> f(&obj, no_op<Foo>);
```

Comment: +1 This is a more generally usable way to declare a `null_deleter` as mentioned in @IgorR's answer.

Comment: @g-makulik well, a much more generally usable way looks like this :-) `struct null_deleter { void operator()(void const *) const {} };`

Answer (score 1):

UPD: Seems there is another, safer, but more verbose and obscure, way using shared_ptr's aliasing constructor with a shared_ptr to an object of any type with the same lifetime. (Sorry, no time to write details).

You can pass  null_deleter in the constructor.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/core/null_deleter.hpp>
int main()
{
   int a = 0;
   boost::shared_ptr<int> pi(&a, boost::null_deleter());
}
```

But watch this case: using object after destruction:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/core/null_deleter.hpp>


class Y
{
public:
    void  tryUse()
    {
         std::cout << "attempt to use :"<< (uintptr_t)(void*)this<< std::endl;
    }
    ~Y()
    {
         std::cout << "destructor: "<< (uintptr_t)(void*)this<< std::endl;
    }
};

struct Y_user
{
     boost::shared_ptr<Y> p;
    ~Y_user()
    {

        std::cout << "Y_user destructor: "<< (uintptr_t)(void*)this<< std::endl;
        if (p.get())
            p->tryUse();
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        Y_user yu;
        Y y;
        boost::shared_ptr<Y> p (&y, boost::null_deleter() );
        yu.p = p;
    }
}
```

Will lead to console output like this:

```
destructor: 140737179995232 
Y_user destructor: 140737179995264
attempt to use :140737179995232
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use c++11 lambda function:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Foo> f(&obj, \[ ](Foo*){});
```