# auto creation and handling of vector of shared pointers

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

Bacially I am learning to handle shared pointers that I want to collect in a vector to have a better control of my objects. Ideally, I would like to have these pointers added to the vector whenever I create a new "Line" object in another class (Rectange). Until recently I have initiated and added shared pointers manually to some vector which worked fine. Having extended some functionality, I have now added a function to the Line class `AddToList()` which automatically adds to a shared pointer. The problem is that when I terminate the programme, it crashes. Otherwise it runs fine and forever without any flaw.

Perhaps the code is flawed or what I have done may not be very safe,

The problem is that I have a rectangle class with holds some line objects. I do not delete any rectangle object explicitly, but when I terminate the programme it crashes at the last instance. I belive I have to make sure that that the pointer to the object stored in the vector is not invalidated. Should I try to do this in the rectangle destructor?

My code is in essence like that:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Line>> vectorOfLines;

Line::Line():
    {
    }

void gLine::AddToList()
        {
        std::shared_ptr<Line> pLine(this);
        vectorOfLines.push_back(pLine);
        }
```

Then I have a Rectangle class whose member is a line object. A rectangle object is created and things run smoothly without any flaws. Only when I ternminate the programme (Hit ESC - exit (0), it crashes at the very end.

Comment: Don't manually delete objects that you're using `shared_ptr`s to.  Make it a `shared_ptr` everywhere and let the refcounting deal with it.

Comment: I do not manually delete the object. But the Line object is nested in another object "rectangle", and at some point when I end the programme, it must call a destructor and it crashes.

Comment: @Dan: I have amended this, it still crashes. It really doesn't matter. I have startd this project 11 years ago, it has 20k lines of code and I have used tr1 as this was at that time what was recommended when I changed from raw pointers. My question is about why it crashes when I terminate the programme.

Comment: The point of smart pointers is managing the lifetime of an object. Once you've passed a pointer to `shared_ptr`, it owns the object and is responsible for deleting it (which also means that you have to make sure it will not be deleted in any other way). If the deletion of `Line` objects is handled by some other class, there is no reason to use `shared_ptr` in the first place.

Comment: But the strange thing is. I am not deleting any rectangle class during my programme. This must come from when I terminate the programme with ESC (exit 0), I guess this calls the destructors and the pointer in the vector is for a splitsecond pointing to nothing.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you explicitly destroy a Rectangle object, if the `Line` object is nested as a member of a `Rectangle` then it's totally wrong to give ownership of the `Line` to a `shared_ptr<Line>`. You should only do that for objects created on the heap, not nested inside other objects. We can't give a more precise answer without seeing more code, what you've shown is useless for explaining the problem. You should also explain exactly what you mean by "is nested inside another obejct" e.g. by showing the code.

Comment: Yes, if the `Rectangle` objects have static or automatic storage duration (if they are not created with the `new` operator), they will be deleted at the end of the program execution (for the static duration) or at the end of the code block (for the automatic duration). Pointers to such objects and their members should not be passed to `shared_ptr`. Although technically it is possible to prevent `shared_ptr` from deleting its object (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830837/can-i-create-a-boostshared-ptr-to-a-local-variable)), it makes much more sense to use raw pointers.

Comment: When the program exits the vector will be destroyed, which will destroy all the `shared_ptr` elements it holds, and that will try to delete all the `Line` objects. If they are not allocated on the heap that will crash. If they are members of another object,  that will crash. It sounds like you don't understand the purpose of `shared_ptr` - you don't use `shared_ptr` "for better control" of objects that don't need to be deleted. But you need to show more code for us to be sure. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic carefully.

Comment: There is not much code to it as I have stripped down to the problem. You essentially explain why it crashes and I am getting now a better understanding of it. The code probject started 11 years ago and I have tried to migrate from raw pointers to shared pointers and am still in the process of learning. But what I don't get is that why downvoting. I indeed did not initialy understand that I should do that for objects created on the heap. How should I know if I don't ask? Perhaps the level of understanding of this community is too high for a basic question like mine. My apologies.

Comment: Please read the link again, you have not stripped down to the problem, you've stripped down to some nonsense snippet of code that isn't valid C++, doesn't even use the same names (is it `Line` or `gLine`?) and doesn't show enough to be meaningful. Read the link again. Read how to create an  [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - that's why the downvote. Not for lack of C++ knowledge, but for asking a poor quality question that doesn't follow the rules of stackoverflow. The question is unclear of not useful, which is what downvotes are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I have a Rectangle class whose member is a line object.

It sounds like you're doing this:

```
struct Rectangle {
  Line line;
};

Rectangle rect;
rect.line.AddToList();  // No!
```

This code is totally broken. It creates a `shared_ptr` that owns the `rect.line` object, but because it's a member of `rect` it is already owned by `rect`, and will be automatically destroyed when `rect` is destroyed. Trying to have it owned (and deleted) by a `shared_ptr` when it is not dynamically allocated is unnecessary and plain wrong.

You don't need "better control" over objects that are members of other objects, because the language and the compiler takes care of that perfectly well already.

Comment: I need to iterate through all line objects. This is what I meant with better control.

Comment: Then use `std::vector<Line*>` not `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Line>>`, so that you have a vector of _non-owning_ pointers, which will not try to delete anything.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us how you create your gLine instances, but most likely the problem is in this line:

```
std::shared_ptr<gLine> pLine(this);
```

By passing `this` to `std::shared_ptr` you are making the shared pointer responsible for deleting the object pointed to by `this`. Unless you create it with `new gLine()`, never delete it afterwards, and call `gLine::AddToList()` exactly once, that would be a problem.

To be able to wrap `this` into a smart pointer, you have a couple of options:

1. Inherit `gLine` from `std::enable_shared_from_this` and then use its `shared_from_this()` member. If you go this route, typically you would make your `gLine` constructor protected and instead provide a static factory method returning `std::shared_ptr<gLine>`.
2. Use `boost::intrusive_ptr` with `boost::intrusive_ref_counter` instead of `std::shared_ptr`. Again, you would probably want a factory method and a protected constructor.

Better yet, redesign your code so that you don't need to wrap `this` into a smart pointer.

Comment: Using `std::enable_shared_from_this` doesn't help in the case where the object was not created on the heap in the first place. And if it was created on the heap in the first place, then there's no problem making it owned by a `shared_ptr` and you don't need `enable_shared_from_this`. The point of `enable_shared_from_this` is to get back a `shared_ptr` when inside some piece of code that only has access to a raw pointer or reference, which is not a common situation.